# Angular JS -- How can I dynamically Change value parameter <input type='button' value="start" /> in angular Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

My requirement is when I clicked on start button one of the Div content must be changed to `"in Progress"` and the `value="start"` must changed to `value="Complete"`, now when I click on "complete button" the div content must changed to Completed and this complete button must be hidden.

I can achieved some of the requirement by Jquery, but I want to implement it by Angular JS. First of all I should know How can I read button `value="start"` in controller of angular Js. Below is my code.

```
<div class="row" style="margin:0% 20% 2% 10%;">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 text-center">
                 18/5/2015
            </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 text-center">
             eureQa 
            </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 text-center">
               Int-1
            </div>

    <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 text-center" id="status">
               Pending
            </div>
             <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-12 text-center">
                <a href="#" style='color:blue;'><input type="button" value="Start" id="start"></a>
            </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-12 text-center" >
                <a href="#" style='color:blue;'><input type="button" value="Reject" id="reject"></a>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-click to set a scope variable or fire a controller function which sets a scope variable that is watched by ng-show. ng-show and ng-hide are responsible for showing/hiding dom elements.

Comment: Thank You Errata, Can you please Provide me a sample Code. Your help will much appreciated.

Comment: I have coded some fucntionality using Jquery, I am new to Angualr Js.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
$("#start").click(function(){
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="In Progress";
document.getElementById("start").innerHTML="Complete"; 
document.getElementById("reject").value="Abort";
$("#start").attr('id','complete');
if(document.getElementById("complete").value=="complete")
{
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="completed";
document.getElementById("start").style.display = 'none';
}
});
$("#reject").click(function(){
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="Rejected";
document.getElementById("start").style.display = 'none';

});
});

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.buttonName  = 'start';
```

onload Declare  a  value  for  button and   in  trigger  change  value  for  the

```
{{buttonName}}
$scope.buttonName  = 'tempName';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the value at all. ng-model takes care of it,

Add `$scope.value` and replace value when you required